# Using belongsToMany relationship i want to return active employees

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

In Skill model

```
public function employee_skill()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employees::class, 'employee_skills', 'skill_id', 'employee_id');
}
```

In Employee model

```
public function skills()
{
      return $this->belongsToMany(Skill::class, 'employee_skills', 'employee_id', 'skill_id');
}
```

I have a EmployeeSkill model and in employee_skills table columns are
id, employee_id, skill_id

I use this for skills based employee count
{{ $skill->employee_skill->count() }}

But i want to return only active employee.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a where clause to your employee_skill relationship:

```
public function employee_skill()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Employees::class, 'employee_skills', 'skill_id', 'employee_id')
    ->where('status', 'Active');
}
```

or if you want to leave it open:

```
$skill->employee_skill->where('status', 'Active')->count()
```